# Why is learning command line imporatant?

Tags: linux, command-line, terminal

I googled this question many times but could not find a good reason why the knowledge of command line is important.Some say GUI cannot be used always but there are no examples supporting their statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On command line you need to learn a few comparatively low level but extremely flexible tools, which serve as building blocks for anything more complex. You only need to learn them once and you can combine them later for any task you need to do.

GUI-based tools tend to be more powerful, but also tend to be more specialized and inflexible. - They are good for one single (complex) task. If you need to do something else you need to find another tool, hope it is doing exactly the right thing and you then need to learn how to use yet another tool.